# Perforce p4 sync works but the python library fails

Tags: python, perforce

We switched to the python library to make it better integrated with our snippets, but it has some weird side-fx and only some operations behave other than the CLI version.

We were running the following command:

`p4 sync //depot/test/...#head` which would return `file(s) up-to-date, however doing the same thing with tye python API.

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception

p4 = P4()
p4.port = "ssl:test:1666"
p4.user = "test-bot"
p4.client = "test-bot_projectX_wing0044"


p4.connect()
print("before run sync")
print p4.run_sync("{}/...#head".format("//depot/projectX"))
print("after run sync")
p4.disconnect()

if p4.errors:
    print(p4.errors)
if p4.warnings:
    print(p4.warnings)
```

Output:

```
python V:\tests\minimal.py
    before run sync
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "V:\tests\minimal.py", line 11, in <module>
    print p4.run_sync("{}/...#head".format("//depot/projectX"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\P4.py", line 497, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kargs: self.run(cmd, *args, **kargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\P4.py", line 611, in run
    raise e
P4.P4Exception: [P4#run] Warnings during command execution( "p4 sync //depot/projectX/...#head" )

        [Warning]: '//depot/projectX/...#head - file(s) up-to-date.'
```

Doesn't return anything, further, it fails to execute any other p4 command that follows after this statement (between connect and disconnect). Further, any `print` statements after this failed operation are omitted. We are running this snippet in a try-catch block, however, `run_sync` doesn't seem to throw.

**Edit: Based on samwise's comment**
I was catching `p4.errors` with `P4Exception` I've expanded that to `p4.warnings` and now I'm seeing `Warnings during command execution( "p4 sync //depot/project/...#head")`

However, that is exactly the same command that's being executed when I have `p4v` opened  and I do a right mouse click on `//depot/project` and do `get latest revision`

Comment: Does `run_sync` actually complete or does it get stuck there?  Did you check for errors/warnings?  Are you sure your connection settings are correct?

Comment: Check out this answer for tips on making sure you're seeing all the errors/warnings coming back from a P4Python command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60285961/3799759

Comment: Oh, I just caught the "`print` statements aren't executed" part.  Yeah, the sync is just taking a long time, maybe because you're running it against a different workspace that's not up to date already?  Or maybe you're using an output handler that's blocking?  Or maybe you ran something earlier in the script that's holding a workspace lock?  Try setting up a minimum reproducible example (I bet the problem will go away once you run this in isolation from the rest of your script)...

Comment: I've realized, this happens only if I do `print p4.run_sync()` If I don't have the print there, the next statements (print and p4) seem to work.

Comment: Might be some quirk of Python 2's `print` statement?  What if you add the `__future__` import and parens so `print` is being called as a function?

Comment: i did impmort '__import__' and converted the print statements to `print()` but that didn't help :(

Comment: Maybe just assign the `run_sync` return value to a variable and print it later?  /shrug

Answer (score 0):

Here you are getting warning exception, You can solve it by exception level.

```
p4 = P4()
p4.port = "ssl:test:1666"
p4.user = "test-bot"
p4.client = "test-bot_projectX_wing0044"

p4.exception_level = 1 #it is 2 by default which means raise all.
p4.connect()
```

Refer Docs [Perforce Exception](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.at_exception_level)